# Throw an exception if one of the parameters is not declared in the CLI command using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface, cypress, package.json

Actual results are: 
I just got a run and nothing happens even after waiting for a half an hour. 
[image: Actual result]

Expected results are: 
To throw a specific exception if a specific parameter is missing.

I don't have currently any error messages. If I try to run it with for example PAGE_TITLE equal to undefined nothing happens.

Tried scenarios:
I put all of the constants which are located in package.json, docker:test-data-creation:add-widgets in a constant array called requiredFields and afterwards call requiredFields from a validateParameters function which doesn't work for unknown reason.

Show some code: 
This is where I call --spec from with specific parameters

```
    "docker:test-data-creation:add-widgets": "XSOCK=/tmp/.X11-unix && XAUTH=/tmp/.docker.xauth && xauth nlist :0 | sed -e 's/^..../ffff/' | xauth -f $XAUTH nmerge - && chmod 755 $XAUTH && docker run --rm -it -v $XSOCK:$XSOCK -v $XAUTH:$XAUTH -e XAUTHORITY=/tmp/.docker.xauth -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY --network=sity_static-network -v $PWD:/test -w /test cypress/included:3.8.1 --browser chrome --env baseUrl=http://symfony.local,PAGE_TITLE='Slider Swiper Widget Test',MAX_WIDGETS_IN_PAGE=50,TOTAL_WIDGETS_COUNT=250,WIDGET_TYPE='SliderSwiper',WIDGETS_WITH_ROWS=50 --spec 'cypress/integration/creation/dynamically_add_widgets_spec.js'"
```

Part if the dynamically_add_widgets_spec.js

```
   * Name of the page where you like to save this widgets
   */
  const PAGE_TITLE = Cypress.env('PAGE_TITLE');

  /**
   * Maximum widgets in the page
   */
  const MAX_WIDGETS_IN_PAGE = Cypress.env('MAX_WIDGETS_IN_PAGE');

  /**
   * Number of total widgets to be added to the page
   */
  const TOTAL_WIDGETS_COUNT = Cypress.env('TOTAL_WIDGETS_COUNT');

  /**
   * Just change the type of the widget to select your needed widget
   */
  const WIDGET_TYPE = Cypress.env('WIDGET_TYPE');

  /**
   * This variable is needed because we want to build some widgets with rows and some widgets don't need rows. The number below is how many widgets one need with rows.
   */
  const WIDGETS_WITH_ROWS = Cypress.env('WIDGETS_WITH_ROWS');

  /**
   * This is a variable that is used to count needed widgets with rows. This variable should always stay 0.
   */
  let ROWS_COUNTER = 0;

  /**
   * This constant is used to determine if all required fields are declared in the cli command
   */
  const requiredFields = [
    PAGE_TITLE,
    MAX_WIDGETS_IN_PAGE,
    TOTAL_WIDGETS_COUNT,
    WIDGET_TYPE,
    WIDGETS_WITH_ROWS
  ];
```

This is where I call it from

```
context("Dynamically create widgets", () => {
    validateParameters(requiredFields);
    createWidgets(WIDGET_TYPE, TOTAL_WIDGETS_COUNT, MAX_WIDGETS_IN_PAGE, WIDGETS_WITH_ROWS);
  });
```

validateParameters function -->

```
  function validateParameters(requiredFields) {
    requiredFields.forEach((field) => {
      if (Cypress.env(field) !== undefined) {
        return;
      }
      throw {message: `Field ${field} is required. Please provide it using --env ${field}. Please look at README.md for an example.`};
    })
  }
```

P.S. I am aware that this forEach couldn't work because I need a specific message if a specific parameter is missing, but I am trying to get to this message and afterwards to get to a specific message if a specific parameter is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that in `validateParameters` function you have passed array of constants. Each constant will have value for example `PAGE_TITLE = Cypress.env('PAGE_TITLE')`; so it will be anything that is defined in `.env`. That could be string, number, undefined or something else.

To solve problem you need to check if passed field is not undefined.

```
function validateParameters(requiredFields) {
    requiredFields.forEach((field) => {
      if (field !== undefined) {
        return;
      }
      throw {message: `Field ${field} is required. Please provide it using --env ${field}. Please look at README.md for an example.`};
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already setting the requiredFields variable above with Cypress.env('...') so you don't need to call it again.

The cypress docs state that Cypress.env('...') returns, the variable or undefined.

```js
    /**
     * Returns specific environment variable or undefined
     * @see https://on.cypress.io/env
     * @example
     *    // cypress.json
     *    { "env": { "foo": "bar" } }
     *    Cypress.env("foo") // => bar
     */
    env(key: string): any
```

See more about Cypress env here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Overriding-Configuration